# Text parsing using regex to create a dictionary from list of strings

Tags: python, regex

Using the following command I am able to parse strings except for some mismatch:

```
re.compile("(?P<Date>\d{2}[.-]\d{2}[.-]\d{4})\s(?P<Item_Name>.+)\s(?P<Transaction_Amount>[\d,\.\s\d]+)\s(?P<Balance>[\d,\.\s\d]+)")
```

If I apply this to a list of strings:

```
['07-10-2019 BIL/INFT/somenumbers/82D3/ AJAY KUMAR 6,080.00 2,46, 287.08',
 '08.10.2019 MOBILE BANKING MMM TiMPS/somenumbers/ SIHDFC 4,411.00 250,698.08']
```

the output is

```
    [{'Date': '07-10-2019', 'Item_Name': 'BIL/INFT/somenumbers/82D3/ AJAY KUMAR 6,080.00', 'Transaction_Amount': '2,46,', 'Balance': '287.08'}, 
{'Date': '08.10.2019', 'Item_Name': 'MOBILE BANKING MMM TiMPS/somenumbers/ SIHDFC', 'Transaction_Amount': '4,411.00', 'Balance': '250,698.08'}]
```

So, the second dictionary output is correct .
In the first output, it seems due to an extra space in 2,46, 287.08, the number 6.080.00 is getting clubbed with Item_Name and Transaction_Amount , Balance is incorrect. Any way to rectify this?

Comment: `(?P<Item_Name>.+)` => `(?P<Item_Name>.+?)`

Comment: Try reformatting your amount regex (?P<Transaction_Amount>[\d,\s\d]+\.[\d]+)\s(?P<Balance>[\d,\s\d]+\.[\d]+)

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks!! Your method and (?P<Transaction_Amount>[0-9,\.]+)\s(?P<Balance>[0-9,\.\s]+) worked well.